# Python: how to "kill" a class instance/object with several references

Tags: python-3.x, class

I need to delete/kill an instance of a class, but it may have references in variables in some other classes. Who knows how I can make it easy?

```py
is_instance_exist = True

def check_vars():
    try:
        print('var1:' + str(var1))
    except:
        print('No var1')
    try:
        print('var2:' + str(var2))
    except:
        print('No var2')

def instance_deleted():
    global is_instance_exist
    is_instance_exist = False

def check_instance():
    global is_instance_exist
    print("Is instance exist: " + str(is_instance_exist))

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, inn):
        self.tt = inn

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tt

    def change(self, inn):
        self.tt = inn

    def __del__(self):
        instance_deleted()

# ---------------------------------------
print("---1--- Create instance of class")
var1 = TestClass('5')
var2 = var1
check_vars()
check_instance()
# ---------------------------------------
print("---2--- Instance connectivity check")
var1.change('6')
check_vars()
check_instance()
# ---------------------------------------------------
print("---2--- Deleting var1")
del var1
check_vars()
check_instance()
# ---------------------------------------------------
print("---3--- Deleting var2")
del var2
check_vars()
check_instance()
# ---------------------------------------------------
print("---The end---")
```

### **Removing every variable is very difficult.**
**Does anyone know how I can do this easily?**

.....................................

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to delete an instance if there is a reference to that instance. Python uses a garbage collector, so no way to release the memory if still in use.

If you want to access an instance in multiple places in your code, and still be able to delete the instance from one place, you can wrap your instance in an object/array/dict and only ever reference the wrapper. This way only your wrapper has a reference and you can delete that reference.

```py
memory = {}
memory["var1"] = 1
memory["var2"] = 2
memory2 = memory
print(memory["var1"])
print(memory["var2"])

del memory["var1"]
try:
    print(memory["var1"])
except:
    print('var1 deleted')

# we can delete from the other reference and it is deleted from both
del memory2["var2"]
try:
    print(memory["var2"])
except:
    print('var2 deleted')
```

**Update**
Like mention in answer from jsbueno https://stackoverflow.com/a/74268773/20351074, weak references can be used instead of a normal/strong reference, where weak references do not increment the reference count and will not prevent the garbage collection to occur.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html

> However, until the object is actually destroyed the weak reference may return the object even if there are no strong references to it.

Comment: Elegant solution)) But not exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: your answer is overall ok as a "way to do it" - it just happens that the language has the features the OP asked for - implemented as support to weak references.

Comment: @jsbueno that makes since. I took it as in a case with having strong references, there doesn't seem to be a way to delete them in that manner with out wrapping it to keep from incrementing the count. Using the weakref does make more since though, I didn't know about them.

Answer (score 0):

While it would be possible to do that, through the use of Python introspection tools, that is not normally done.

Doing that with *regular* references would be poossible by using the garbage collector interface in the `gc` stdlib module: that allows you to find all references to your object, and then you could go about setting every reference to your object to `None` - that would not be straightforward, tough: there are places were you'd have to set an attribute, other places where the rerence would be in a map key, or a map value, and sometimes it would be the member of a sequence - but most importantly, all the "users" of this instance must be "aware" that it might become a "None" at any time, and do not rely on that element always being an instance of your class.

Which leads us to the *actual* pattern Python has to deal with that: weakreferences.

Weakreferences do exactly what you want: they simply "vanish" along with the original object. The only drawback is that everywhere it is used have to make a use compatible with it vanishing.

Fortunately, the stdlib 'weakref' module itself brings some possibilities: proxies,sets and mappings. And then, you have to be careful to just pass weak-references of your "vanishing" object to all places that will use it, and only keep a single strong reference (i.e. a normal reference), in a place the code that wants to kill then have control.

You should check the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html

Check in this sample code as the instances "vanish" from the `WeakSet` refences as they are deleted from the `real_instances`  list which keeps the sole non-weak references to them.

```
from weakref import WeakSet

class A:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = self.__class__.counter
        self.__class__.counter += 1
    def print(self):
        print(f"{self.id} is alive")


real_instances = []
weak_instances = WeakSet()

def use_objects(mylist):
    for obj in mylist:
        obj.print()

def main():
    for i in range(4):
        a = A()
        real_instances.append(a)
        weak_instances.add(a)
        del a
    while real_instances:
        use_objects(weak_instances)
        real_instances.pop()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, everyone, especially [@jsbueno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108205/jsbueno), I chose to solve the problem using the standard library [wakref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.ref):

```
import weakref

is_instance_exist = None

def check_vars(va1, var2):
    try:
        print('var1:' + var1.tt)
    except:
        print('No var1')
    try:
        print('var2:' + var2.tt)
    except:
        print('No var2')


def check_instance():
    global is_instance_exist
    print("Is instance exist: " + str(is_instance_exist))


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._tt = value
        global is_instance_exist
        is_instance_exist = True

    @property
    def tt(self):
        return self._tt

    def change(self, value):
        self._tt = value

    def __del__(self):
        global is_instance_exist
        is_instance_exist = False

# ---------------------------------------
print("---1--- Create instance of class")
var1 = TestClass('5')
var2 = weakref.ref(var1)
check_vars(var1, var2())
check_instance()
# ---------------------------------------
print("---2--- Instance connectivity check")
var1.change('6')
check_vars(var1, var2())
check_instance()
# ---------------------------------------------------
print("---2--- Deleting var1")
del var1
check_vars(None, var2())
check_instance()
# ---------------------------------------------------
print("---The end---")
```